# Is there an easier/faster way to view Github page

Tags: github, github-pages

I am wondering if there is a more simple/quicker way to view a github page from its repo instead of navigating through settings and clicking the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really.

You could script a call to [GitHub Pages API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/pages/#enable-a-pages-site), which mentions:

> Enabling and disabling Pages in the Pages API is currently available for developers to preview

So that call could do:

```
POST /repos/:owner/:repo/pages
```

That would enable Pages, exactly like when you navigating through settings and click the link.

Comment: Thanks! It is so annoying have to type out the link but i guess its just me being lazy lol. All that great tech and they dont add a simple button to link live view lol.